# Eventlet WSGI server logging won't stop

Tags: python, wsgi, eventlet

Good morning,

We are facing a rather odd issue with Eventlet and WSGI server on Python. We are trying to stop it from logging these lines

```
(5757) accepted ('y.x.z.88', 52344)
(5757) accepted ('y.x.z.88', 52621)
```

We have tried the following settings in the WSGI server setup

```
wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('1.2.3.4', 8000),
                                backlog=10000), hello_world, max_size=10000, log=None,log_output=False)
```

Can anyone tell us why log=None or log_output=False is not stopping the above lines?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thomas.

It was still logging those messages because `log_output` check was not applied to them.

The issue is fixed in master and will be included in next PyPI release.

To get it right now, use:

`pip install https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/archive/61fc317c22a84201beabe892f61a30ae59206aba.zip`

Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you I shall check out the archive later today.